# How to call different index files for main domain and sub domains?

Tags: .htaccess, url, subdomain

I have a site in the name of www.mysite.com. when the url is www.mysite.com,  I want to call index1.php file (this is my main domain).

If the url is from sub domains like test1.mysite.com, test2.mysite.com then I want to call index2.php file.

How to do it in htaccess?

Answer (score 1):

If they are both in the same document root, put something like this in your htaccess file in the document root:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index2.php [L]
```

If you have links to directory indexes that need to be rewritten, you can do those on a case-by-case basis, for example:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(php|html|htm)$ /$1/index1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)/index\.(php|html|htm)$ /$1/index2.php [L]
```

Comment: if i want to call index1.php from root directory and index2.php from other sub folder means, how to change this code?

Comment: @jeeva what does that have to do with main domains and sub domains?

Comment: RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^(www\.)?mysite\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index2.php [L] I've added this code into my .htaccess file. Now main domain is not working(www.mysite.com), but sub-domains(test1.mysite.com, test2.mysite.com) are working fine. Now both index files are in root directory.

Comment: thanks for your reply .. yes, when i give  http://www.mysite.com/index1.php in url its working fine. but i don't want either index1.php or index2.php to be displayed in url. waiting for your reply.

Comment: @jeeva no idea what's wrong, I put the top set of 2 rules into a blank htaccess file, and I go to `http://mysite.com/` or `http://www.mysite.com/` and I see the contents of my index1.php file.