# How to call different index file using .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, call

How to call different index file using .htaccess ?

I need to put a link on my site that I need to load homepage but with different index file (index2.html) but the url to be www.mysite.com and not www.mysite.com/index2.html

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?mysite\.com\index2.html$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^$ /index2.php [L]
```

Above rule didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

```
DirectoryIndex newfile.php newfile.html site-down.php
```

should do the trick in .htaccess

Comment: just write this line to a new .htaccess file that should work, i didnt try actually, i'm using nginx but as far as i remember, its like this in apache. No need for rewritecond and rewriterule to make this.

Comment: I try it. It didn't work. I need when access myiste.com/index2.html to load the index2.html content but on browser url to see only www.mysite.com and not  myiste.com/index2.html

Comment: just to make things clear;
www.mysite.com => which page will load as default page?

Comment: index.html is default for everyone, but I have one link that I need to load index2.html withaut showing index2.html in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I Think what you are looking for is not possible with htaccess, its totally browser based.. so in your index2.html file add this to the body, this is HTML5 so i am not sure if it works below ie9.

```
<script> window.history.replaceState('Object', 'Title', '/'); </script>
```

Comment: I paste the code as you writte it with no results. This person had the same issue I don't understand how he solve it http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12312906/how-to-call-different-index-files-for-main-domain-and-sub-domins